# Unexpected token <, javascript files being rendered as html?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http

Im setting up a server using node.js, it loads the html file, and then the html file loads in the javascript scripts. When looking at the dev tools in chrome, it shows the error "Unexpected token <", and when I inspected further, it shows that the javascript files were loaded as html files for some reason.

Ive tried to look at other answers online but I can't figure out the issue here...

index.js rendered as html: https://gyazo.com/1d56121bfa169be139a3eb7d263a4785

Server file that gets ran on start

```
let http = require('http');
let fs = require('fs');

let handleRequest = (request, response) => {
    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    fs.readFile('./index.html', null, function (error, data) {
        if (error) {
            response.writeHead(404);
            respone.write('Whoops! File not found!');
        } else {
            response.write(data);
        }
        response.end();
    });
};

http.createServer(handleRequest).listen(8000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Snek</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>A</h4>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="600" style="background-color: gray">Unsupported canvas</canvas>
</body>
<script src="/scripts/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

The idea is that the server.js gets ran, reads the html file, and the html file loads the js scripts.

Comment: The browser will issue HTTP requests back to your server when it sees those `<script>` tags. Your server looks like it's only prepared to do one thing, which is to respond with the `index.html` content no matter what the URL looks like.

Comment: `Unexpected token <` usually means that something regarding javascript was expected but your server returned HTML. I think @Pointy is correct.